# The Tor log says it's failed

Tags: relays

I loaded Tor as a Relay, I wanted to know if its working so went to the `/var/log/tor` file,
and right at the bottom it says:

```
    May 04 16:14:19.000[notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
    May 04 16:14:19.000[notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
    May 04 16:14:19.000[notice] Now checking whether ORPort 82.3.5.110:443 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes - - look for log messages indicating success)
    May 04 16:15:18.000[notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 105 buildtimes.
    May 04 16:24:18.000[notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 100 buildtimes.
    May 04 16:29:25.000[notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 100 buildtimes.
    May 04 16:33:52.000[notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 100 buildtimes.
    May 04 16:34:04.000[warn] Your server (82.3.5.110:443) has not managed to confirm its ORPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable.
    Please check you firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
```

I' am lost as what to do now .

Thanks for the info.
I Have a Virginmeadia Router, I went and found the port forwarding section .
I checked my Ip via ifconfig - it said it was 192.168.0.18
So on the port forwrding section of the router I gave it a Name TorRelay then added port 443 start and 443 end and added the IP address as above.
checking the the  /var/tor/log  file I saw it was showing a new page 
May 05 11:13:52:000 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.10 (git-e28303bcf90b842d) opening new log file.
May 05 11:14:50:000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside.
Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.
May 05 11:14:50:000 [notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.

Does this mean I have configured my router properly, The IP address is not a static one, if I now have to turn the TOR relay of for any reason will I have to reconfigure the Virginmedia Hub again?

Thanks, setting up the IP address in my virgin media hub has worked, my Relay is now listed in the Atlas web site so thanks everyone.

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check any local firewall or packet filters allow inbound traffic on port 443.

If you're behind a NAT device (e.g. you connect from a private IP address like *192.168.100.2* to some router like *192.168.100.1* to connect out to the internet) then you need to configure that device to set up a NAT forwarding rule, so that connections coming in to the router on port 443, get forwarded to your internal IP (*192.168.100.2*).

Essentially, people trying to connect *in* to your relay, are currently unable to do so. Something between them and your router is stopping the connection making it though.

In your case, with a non-static IP address, Tor should detect it's IP address automatically. If the IP changes it will republish it's descriptor with the new IP and the port forwarding config should remain in place and working on the new IP. Your relay will be unusable from the time that it changes until the next top of the hour (e.g. 01:00, 14:00, etc).

What you *may* want to do is to setup a DHCP reservation, if that's available. If the LAN IP address changes then you'll need to reconfigure the port forwarding since it'll be pointing to the wrong LAN IP address. If setting up a DHCP reservation isn't possible, you might want to configure it as a static IP address outside of the range assigned by DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you turn the relay off, but possibly if you turn your router off and your computer is assigned a new LAN IP.

Make your IP static both on the router side and computer 
side. For "Preferred DNS server" enter the routers LAN IP, e.g. 192.168.1.1 for asus.